# Asignar valor por defecto a un select que se llena con ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ionic

El problema es el siguiente:
  tengo varios select los dos primero de región y provincias se llenan solamente, pero el de ciudades depende de la provincia seleccionada y el de poligono se muestra solo cuando se selecciona la ciudad de valdivia,pero cuando no se selecciona esta ciudad lo ideal es que se le pueda asignar un valor por defecto,ya que si lo dejo asi queda como undefined y me genera problemas, alguien que piense mas rápido que yo porfavor su ayuda

```
.factory('poligono', function(){
var poligonos = [
    {idPoligono:'1',nombrePoligono:'Poligono A'},
    {idPoligono:'2',nombrePoligono:'Poligono B'}
];
return{
    getPoligonos: function(){
        return poligonos;
    }
}
})
```

este es mi codigo HTML

```
    <form id="page-form1" class="list">
  <label class="item item-select" id="page-select1">
    <span >Región</span>
    <!--<select ng-options="elemento.idRegion as elemento.nombreRegion for elemento in region" ng-model="reg">
           <option value="">--Seleccione Una Opción--</option>
    </select>-->
    <select ng-options="elemento.idRegion as elemento.nombreRegion for elemento in regioness" ng-model="reg">
           <option value="">--Seleccione Una Opción--</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <label class="item item-select" id="page-select2">
    <span class="input-label">Provincia</span>
    <!--<select ng-model="pro" ng-change="cargarCiudades(pro)" ng-options="item.idProvincia as item.nombreProvincia for item in provincias" id="provin">
        <option value="">--Seleccione Una Opción--</option>
    </select>-->
    <select ng-model="pro"  ng-change="cargarCiudades(pro)" ng-options="item.idProvincia as item.nombreProvincia for item in provinciass" id="provin">
        <option value="">--Seleccione Una Opción--</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-select" id="page-select3">
    <span class="input-label">Ciudad</span>
    <!--item.idCiudad as item.nombreCiudad for item in ciudad -->
    <select  ng-options="dato.idCiudad as dato.nombreCiudad for dato in ciudadess" ng-model="ciu">
        <option value="">--Seleccione Una Opción--</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <div id="page-container1" class="creator-container">


      <label class="item item-select" id="page-select4" ng-show="ciu == 1">
   //HE AQUI MI PROBLEMA 
        <span class="input-label">Poligono</span>
        <select ng-model="poli" ng-init="poli = options[0]" ng-options="item.idPoligono as item.nombrePoligono for item in poligono">
              <option value="0" selected = "selected">--seleccione Poligono--</option>
              <!--<option value="1">Poligono A</option>
              <option value="2">Poligono B</option>-->
        </select>
  </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo tengo resuelto con `ng-selected` así:

```
<option ng-selected="obj.propiedad==valor">OPTION1</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para asignar un valor por defecto a un select el camino más fácil es con ng-init="value_option".

Te adjunto un pequeño ejemplo:

```
<select class="form-control" id="seleccion" ng-init="valorBusqueda='valor_usuario'" ng-model="valorBusqueda">
        <option value="valor_usuario">Usuarios</option>
        <option value="valor_escuelas">Escuelas de escalada</option>
</select>
```

Muy importante no confundir el atributo value de la opción con el texto de la opción.
Espero haberte ayudado! =)